# Scrollbar isn't showing up in the website

Tags: html, css, web, scrollbar

The scroll bar isn't showing up in the website even after putting

```
{
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

in the body or html css

[Link](http://www.hillnut.com/clients/wcb/agi)

Would be glad if some one could help me on this

Comment: Add more content and check whether the scroll appears or not. May be it is not showing due to your main div height.

Comment: First, please read up on [ask] as well as on [mcve]. Second, maybe some JavaScript is hiding the scroll bar?

Comment: Hi @krr25 , there is already a lot of content in the page, but still it is not showing up

Comment: Got it working Thanks!!

Comment: @TarunSubramanyaKondapalli what did you change?

Comment: my css had body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
} so i commented it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your style.css and remove these lines. Other than that it works fine on non-webkit browsers

[image: Untitled.png]

I hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

in your styles.css comment this code to make scrollbar visible on chrome

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /* display: none; */
}
```